# Matlab: Multiply vertical axis of hist plot by a number

Tags: matlab, histogram

The hist function in matlab plots the frequency of the data points in the vertical axis. What should I do if I want to multiply the frequency by a number.

For example if an object points at North 10 times during the entire recording of data and each time, it stays in the North position for 5 seconds. Instead of having the hist plot show that the object pointed at North 10 times, I would like it to show that it pointed at North for a total of 50 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) (or [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) in 2014b) function to do the bin counting without plotting the data, then plot using bar.

```
directions = rand(1000, 1)*360;
% note that histc counts the last element as exactly equal, so I pad
edges = [0:5:360, inf]; 
counts = histc(directions, edges);

multiplier = 5;

bar(edges(1:end-1)*multiplier, counts(1:end-1))
```